# Jacoco 0.8.2>= + Java 11 + Spring 5 not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit, jacoco

I'm getting the following error when attempting to "Run Coverage" as junit test:
[image]

All I can really find is that Java 11 support began at version 0.8.2 for jacoco, which I've updated but I still haven't been able to resolve the issue, does anyone have any suggestions?

[image]

`mvn clean install`:

[image: mvn clean install result]

pitest:
[image]

Comment: Please show a full working example...

Comment: @khmarbaise what is it exactly you'd like to see, the test itself?

Comment: Please show the failing test code including the console output of the build and pom.xml would be helpful, because there are many deps (mockito, pitest, jacoco) which are not up-to-date ...also I assume the usage mockito with UUID usually fails because the majority of the people do it wrong ...

Comment: @khmarbaise I've added some extra screen shots. This worked prior to upgrading to  java 11 / spring 5, also I am using JDK 16 locally not sure if that's making the issue worse

Answer (score 0):

In regards to errors during `mvn clean test` the project is java 11 but my local JRE was java 16, downgrading to java 11 fixed this.

For the "Run Coverage As" portion my local eclipse has eclema 2.3.2, eclema was replaced by jacoco and java 11 support was introduced in jacoco 0.8.2 and eclema 3.1.1 respectively:

https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.eclemma.doc%2Fpages%2Fchanges.html
[image]

In my case running `mvn org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:report` generated a report in `../target/site/jacoco/index.html` which shows the coverage I need.